# How to make checkbox checked automatically?

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox

Hello I need some help making the checkbox I made checked automatically. I'm using this code to insert the checkbox in the checkout on Woocommerce.

What code can I use to make the checkbox checked?

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['mc4wp-try-subscribe'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Newsletter', 'woocommerce'),
    'type'=> 'checkbox',
    'required'  => false,
    'checked' => true,
    'value' => '1',
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your array:

```
'checked' => true
```

Comment: Hello Dennis thank you for your response but i added the code you gave me and still wont work, i updated my code with your code in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
'checked' => 'checked'
```

I hope help you ;-)

Comment: Thank you Jose but the code still won't work, is there another code I can try or other way I can do this.